# openpyxl reader returns None values

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl, nonetype

I'm trying to read xlsx document using `openpyxl` module. The problem is that it behaves like there was `none` values each second row.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook('x.xlsx', use_iterators=True)
first_sheet = workbook.get_sheet_names()[0]
worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(first_sheet)

for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        print cell.value
```

It returns:

```
    None None None None None None None
    value value value value value value value
    None None None None None None None
    value value value value value value value
    None None None None None None None
    value value value value value value value
    ....
```

Do you know how to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

Either the code you're using is different or the file alternates between rows with values and empty rows.

See https://bitbucket.org/snippets/openpyxl/ok6o

Answer (score 1):

This is very late, but in case anyone in the future cares:
I get this error when I include "use_iterators=True".  If I delete this argument, it works fine.